# CSS for removing padding (margin?) in a submit button

Tags: html, css, form-submit, submit-button

I've been trying to delete a padding (margin?) from a submit (send form) button and apply font, color, etc., but it hasn't been possible to make the code work in the [website form](http://builder.ferozo.com/1589630/#!/-contact-us/?ancla=FREE+QUOTE).

```
input[type=submit] {
  color: red;
  font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #595959;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

What part of the CSS code is missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
.form-actions {
    padding: 19px 20px 20px; // Here is your problem
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #aea790;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

The padding is coming from the form-action div (the buttons container), not the input.

Comment: The web builder only allows me to add CSS code in the template (not modify the exitisting one) but the .form-actions command helped me to remove the padding. What I can't change yet are the font-family and the font-size. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's because the submit button you're trying to target isn't actually an `input`. It's just a `<button>` within a div.

Try this to target the right element:

```
.form-actions {
    color: red;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #595959;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Comment: The web builder only permits to add CSS code in the template (not modify the exitisting one) but the .form-actions command helped me to remove the padding and change background-color. What I can't change yet are the font-family and the font-size. Thanks